# Is there a way to edit a result object in YOLOv8? (pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, yolov8

### I tried to edit a property from a result type that I get from the ` model.track` function from YOLO

[image]

code:

```
    for result in model.track(source=source, show=False, stream=True, verbose=False):
    frame = result.orig_img
    
    # result.boxes.id[0] = 0 # Code Crash
    print('After', result.boxes.id)
```

### And I got this error:

- RuntimeError: Inplace update to inference tensor outside InferenceMode is not allowed.You can make  a clone to get a normal tensor before doing inplace update.See https://github.com/pytorch/rfcs/pull/17 for more details.

I Read the forum that the error linked me but it was no help.

I tried making another result object and copy every value from it besides the id (the property that I am trying to edit) and it was also a no go

Using the del keyword is also a no go.

I've read in the torch docs (after looking up how to change tensors) about an  Inference Mode option in which I can edit the object but I still haven't managed to use this info to my advantage

### The tensor in question:

[image]

```
After tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

Comment: Could you post your code and results as text? Their current format makes them impossible to search for and copy (more reasons [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)).

Comment: Sorry. I made an update to my post

Comment: Try putting your code inside a [`smart_inference_mode`](https://docs.ultralytics.com/reference/utils/torch_utils/#ultralytics.utils.torch_utils.smart_inference_mode) context manager. It will make it faster and should solve your problem. Alternatively, you could call [`detach_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach_.html) on the tensor before modifying it.

Comment: Please edit your post so as to share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by using the update function inside the results class.
to update the results obj

https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/engine/results.py

Comment: Update? Self-answered questions are cool and encouraged. But please make sure you leave it in a format hat may be useful to future readers (explicit title, trimmed code,... all that is recommended in [ask] and [answer]]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).